# WebService client returns null if run under Java 8

Tags: java, web-services

I have a Web Service (C#, under IIS) and WebService Client (Java code) inside a servlet which is hosted by Apache Tomcat. If Tomcat uses Java 7 then communication with the Web Service works OK, but if Tomcat uses Java 8, Web Service client method (WebMethod) returns null (for complex data). In both cases method of Web Service is invoked and works correctly (I've debugged it under Visual Studio). Here some snippets from my client's code:
proxy:

```
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.3.1-hudson-749-SNAPSHOT
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "BluePrint", targetNamespace = "artifact.wsclient.vuelink.cimmetry.com")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface BluePrint {

************
/**
 * 
 * @param arg1
 * @param arg0
 * @return
 *     returns com.cimmetry.vuelink.wsclient.artifact.WsDocID
 */
@WebMethod
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "openFile", targetNamespace = "artifact.wsclient.vuelink.cimmetry.com", className = "com.cimmetry.vuelink.wsclient.artifact.OpenFile")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "openFileResponse", targetNamespace = "artifact.wsclient.vuelink.cimmetry.com", className = "com.cimmetry.vuelink.wsclient.artifact.OpenFileResponse")
public WsDocID openFile(
    @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
    String arg0,
    @WebParam(name = "arg1", targetNamespace = "")
    SessionData arg1);
```

and call to Web Service:

```
BluePrint proxy = getWSClient(beSession);
*****    
WsDocID docID = proxy.openFile(orginalUrl, data);
```

In case of Java 8 docID variable is null.

Comment: Share some code maybe? And which part is java and which is c#?

Comment: Web Service implemented as WCF service on C#. Client of this Service is running inside Servlet (Java) which hosted under Tomcat.

Comment: Code inside client looks like that 
  WsDocID docID = proxy.openFile(orginalUrl, data);
  
where "proxy" is 
/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.3.1-hudson-749-SNAPSHOT
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 
 */
@WebService(name = "BluePrint", targetNamespace = "artifact.wsclient.vuelink.cimmetry.com")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface BluePrint {
*****

Comment: @WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "openFile", targetNamespace = "artifact.wsclient.vuelink.cimmetry.com", className = "com.cimmetry.vuelink.wsclient.artifact.OpenFile")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "openFileResponse", targetNamespace = "artifact.wsclient.vuelink.cimmetry.com", className = "com.cimmetry.vuelink.wsclient.artifact.OpenFileResponse")
    public WsDocID openFile(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        String arg0,
        @WebParam(name = "arg1", targetNamespace = "")
        SessionData arg1);

Comment: I debug it under Eclipse and if I use Java 7 - WebMethod returns correct value, if I use Java 8 - it returns null. In both cases method is invoked (I checked it under Visual Studio Debugger).

Comment: can you edit your question to include that code - and I'll vote to reopen that